# XML serialization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
class SomeClass
    {
        private int _property1;
        [XmlAttribute("Property1")]
        public int Property1
        {
            get { return _property1; }
            set { _property1 = value; }
        }
        private int _property2;
        [XmlAttribute("Property2")]
        public int Property2
        {
            get { return _property2; }
            set { _property2 = value; }
        }

        private string _property3;
        public string Property3
        {
            get { return _property3; }
            set { _property3 = value; }
        }

        public SomeClass()
        {
        }
    }
```

I need to serialize it using XmlSerializer in the following format:

```
<SomeClass Property1="NNNNN" Property2="NNNNN">
     Value_of_Property3
</SomeClass>
```

However, I can't figure how can I serialize the value of Property3 without adding a node for Property3. Is there a to serialize the string in Property3 without adding a node for it?

Comment: "However, I can't figure how can I serialize the value of Property3 without adding a node for Property3." - May I ask why?

Comment: @Felipe Fiali - Probably security.  Often data that is serialized is unreadable by humans.

Comment: @Chris Yes but that's not the case with XML Serialization. If you want to serialize data in an unreadable by humans form, you often use Binary Serialization. Also, what extra security would serializing an attribute as text give you?

Comment: @Felipe Fiali Well, there's a lot of benefits still even though it is not a Binary Serialization.  SOAP XML Serialization is still used w/ encryption to send data over a secure network even thought it may only be in plain text.  If you would like to learn more, just google SOAP Serialization (XML), it will tell you much more about the benefits than I can.

Comment: @Felipe Fiali But yes, I would have to agree, Binary Serialization all the way to avoid human readability

Comment: @Chris You're terribly missing the point here, Chris. My first comment asked why would he want to add a property as text instead of adding it as an attribute. Then you told me it could be for security reasons, and I just said I didn't see how it would grant more security to serialize a property as text and not as an attribute. And as TEXT I mean XML TEXT instead of XML Attribute.

Comment: @Felipe Fiali Ahh I see.  Sorry about that, must have mis-interpreted your first comment my friend.

Comment: @Chris Don't worry about it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Add `[XmlText()]` attribute to `Property3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[XmlText]
public string Property3
{
    get { return _property3; }
    set { _property3 = value; }
}
```